# Not getting data from MongoDB database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, twitter, backend

I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB database and it's not retrieving any data. I have it set up on MongoDB as Twitter-Clone project, which contains twitter-clone collection with tweets table and users table.

When I launch the app from command line, I'm getting these 2 messages from tweetsDAO.js and index.js respectively:

```
tweetsDAO.js has established collection handles.
Listening on port 5000
```

When I go to http://localhost:5000/api/v1/tweets I'm getting this message from tweets-controller.js, which seems to indicate it ran a search and came back empty:

```
{"tweets":[],"page":0,"filters":{},"entries_per_page":20,"total_results":0}
```

These are the files being used:

.env file:

```
TWITTCLONE_DB_URI=mongodb+srv://admin:<thisismypassword>@twitter-clone.3wvps.mongodb.net/twitter_clone?retryWrites=true&w=majority
TWITTCLONE_NS=twitter_clone
PORT=5000
```

index.js:

```
import app from "./server.js";
import mongodb from "mongodb";  // Used to access mongodb.
import dotenv from "dotenv";    // Used to access environment variables.
import TweetsDAO from "./dao/tweetsDAO.js";
dotenv.config();    // Load in environment variables.
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;    // Access our Mongo client.

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;  // Use port from .env file, or 8000.

MongoClient.connect(    // Connect to database.
    process.env.TWITTCLONE_DB_URI, // The environment variable with username & password for MongoDB.
    {
        wtimeout: 2500,      // After 2500 miliseconds the request times out.
    })
    .catch(err => {      // If error, log to console and exit the process.
        console.error(err.stack);  
        process.exit(1);
    })
    .then(async client => {     // Succesful connection to database.
        await TweetsDAO.injectDB(client);
        app.listen(port, () => {    // Starts our web server.
            console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
        })
    }
);
```

server.js:

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import allRoute from "./api/all.route.js";

const app = express();

app.use(cors());    // Apply our middleware, CORS module.
app.use(express.json());    // Our server can accept JSON in the body of a request. Previously required body-parser, but express can do this now.

app.use("/api/v1/tweets", allRoute);    // Accessed with http://localhost:5000/api/v1/tweets
app.use("*", (req, res) => res.status(404).json({ error: "not found" }));    // A route that doesn't exist in our route file.

export default app; // Export this file as a module.
```

all.route.js:

```
import express from "express";
import TweetsCtrl from "./tweets.controller.js";

const router = express.Router();    // The different routes ppl can go to.

// router.route("/").get((req, res) => res.send("Hello world!"));  // Our demo route. Going to root responds with HW.
router.route("/").get(TweetsCtrl.apiGetTweets);   // Going to root returns this method.

export default router;
```

tweets-controller.js:

```
import TweetsDAO from "../dao/tweetsDAO.js";

export default class TweetsController {
    static async apiGetTweets (req, res, next) {   // User may or may not be passing variables in with the URL.
        const tweetsPerPage = req.query.resturantsPerPage ? parseInt(req.query.tweetsPerPage, 10) : 20  // Checks if tweetsPerPage is being passed in and then converts to an int. Otherwise default is 20 tweets per page.
        const page = req.query.page ? parseInt(req.query.page, 10) : 0  // Checks if page is being passed in and then converts to an int. Otherwise default is page 0.

        let filters = {};   // Filters is set to default.

        const { tweetsList, totalNumTweets } = await TweetsDAO.getTweets({  // Pass in filters, page, & tweetsPerPage. Returns the tweetsList & totalNumTweets.
            filters,
            page,
            tweetsPerPage,
        });

        let response = {    // Return the json response with all this data.
            tweets: tweetsList,
            page: page,
            filters: filters,
            entries_per_page: tweetsPerPage,
            total_results: totalNumTweets,
        }
        res.json(response);
    }
```

tweetsDAO.js:

```
import mongodb from "mongodb";
const ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectId;  // Use ObjectID to convert a String to a MongoDB object.

let tweets;

export default class TweetsDAO {
    static async injectDB(conn) {
        if (tweets) {  // If the tweet already exists.
            return;
        }
        try {
            tweets = await conn.db(process.env.TWITTCLONE_NS).collection("tweets");  // If it doesn't exist already, it will be created when trying to add a document to it.
            console.error("tweetsDAO.js has established collection handles.")
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(`Unable to establish collection handles in tweetsDAO: ${e}`)
        }
    }

    static async getTweets({   // Gets a list of all tweets in the database.
        filters = null,     // Default by null, unless user passes something in.
        page = 0,   // Defaults to page 0.
        tweetsPerPage = 20,    // Defaults to 20 tweets per page.
    } = {}) {
        let query;   // If query isn't set to anything, it returns all tweets.
        if (filters) {  // User can search by name, cuisine, or zipcode.
            if ("name" in filters) {
                query = { $text: { $search: filters["name"] } } // Specified in MongoDB will check a certain field.         
        }

        let cursor;

        try {
            cursor = await tweets
            .find(query)    // Find all tweets in the database that match this query.

        } catch (e) {   // If there is no query, returns an error.
            console.error(`Unable to issue find command, ${e}`);
            return { tweetsList: [], totalNumTweets: 0 }
        }

        const displayCursor = cursor.limit(tweetsPerPage).skip(tweetsPerPage * page); // To locate which page user is on, use the limit and current page to determine what to display.

        try {
            const tweetsList = await displayCursor.toArray();
            const totalNumTweets = await tweets.countDocuments(query);

            return { tweetsList, totalNumTweets }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(
                `Unable to convert cursor to array or problem counting documents, ${e}`
            );
            return { tweetsList: [], totalNumTweets: 0 }
        }
    }
}
```

In another project I am looking at, it seems that submitting an empty query command returns all the data from the table. So I think I have done something wrong but can't figure it out?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out! The .env file had the wrong name for collections. I had twitter_clone, but it's actually twitter-clone. Hyphen, not underscore. Now it's pulling data properly.

Comment: Also got this thing-- `        const tweetsPerPage = req.query.resturantsPerPage ? parseInt(req.query.tweetsPerPage, 10) : 20  // Checks if tweetsPerPage is being passed in and then converts to an int. Otherwise default is 20 tweets per page.` --> I think  you want `req.query.tweetsPerPage?`

Comment: That's true, thanks! I was basing it on an older project and was Find/Replace on a lot of variables. Which doesn't work on spelling errors. XD